# What is the more natural parsing, the one that leads to the preferred reading of the sentence

Tags: nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, linguistics, nltk-book

I have those rules:
[image]

and those two possible parse trees:

[image]

I am asked for the next question:

What is the more natural parsing, the one that leads to the preferred reading of the sentence?

Can anyone explain to me, what is more natural in English and why ?

according to [this](https://sites.google.com/site/partofspeechhelp/#TOC-DT-)

```
A determiner is a noun-modifier that expresses the reference of a noun or noun phrase in the context.
```

I don't see any possible more natural distinguish.

Comment: [Cross-posted](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/87540/64377). Please avoid asking the same question on different SE sites. Also this is not a programming question at all, if anything it's a linguistics question.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take this into account. This question appeared as part of an nlp assignment, but you're right about being it more linguistic less programming related, position accepted.